# JS: JSON retrieve all JSON data

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON object which looks like:

```
    var ob = {
              "a":[
                   "a1",
                   "a2"
                   ],
              "b":[
                   "b1",
                   "b2"
                   ],
              "c":[
                   "c1",
                   "c2"
                   ]
              }
```

I am trying to populate the JSON values/data (a1, a2, b1, b2, c1, c2) into a div.
I can populate a, b, c using `for loop` but I don't know how to get "inner" data.
Experts please help me.
(I am new to JavaScript)

Comment: There's not enough information here. What should the end result look like?

Answer (score 0):

```
    var ob = {
          "a":[
               "a1",
               "a2"
               ],
          "b":[
               "b1",
               "b2"
               ],
          "c":[
               "c1",
               "c2"
               ]
          }
```

var keys = Object.keys(ob)

console.log(keys)

keys.forEach(key => {console.log(ob[key])})

Answer (score -1):

First vocabulary. That is not JSON but a javascript object. JSON is a string that you could use to represent that object. If you don't have a string, it's not JSON.

You get inner "data" (array items and object properties) by doing something like this. `ob.a[0] // "a1"`  Dots to access child properties of objects. Hard brackets and index to get the item of an array. You can use hard brackets and property-id to get objects (such as: `ob["a"][0] // "a1"`) You set the data of those properties like with any other. `ob.a[0] = "something";`

You can add new values to arrays by [pushing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) them.

```
ob.a.push("a3");
```

If you need to edit an item but and not know the index, you can find it using `.indexOf()` which gives the position of the item in the array (or -1 if not found):

```
var index = ob.a.indexOf("a2");
if (index > -1) {
    ob.a[index] = "a2.b";
}
```

Or you can loop through the inner array:

```
for(var i=0; i<ob.a.length;i++){ 
  ob.a[i] = "a" + i;
}
```